# Create dummy object of non-default-constructible class

Tags: c++, c++14, default-constructor, sentinel

tl;dr: I want to construct a class *ListEntry* containing a member of a generic type *Value*, but *Value* is not default constructible and *ListEntry* doesn't know how to construct it. I will never access this *Value* member, so it doesn't matter that it isn't initialized.

**Why I'm doing this**

I'm implementing a double linked list roughly similar to the following

```
template<class Value>
class ListEntry {
  Value value;
  ListEntry<Value> *prev;
  ListEntry<Value> *next;
};
template<class Value>
class List {
  ListEntry<Value> sentinel;
};
```

The links between the list entries always form a closed circle where the sentinel connects the last list element to the first list element. The sentinel object is initialized with sentinel.prev = &sentinel and sentinel.next = &sentinel.

This way, I get rid of a lot of special cases and I never have to check for nullptr because there are no null pointers. Adding an element to the end of the list (between the last element and the sentinel) is not a special case but the same as adding an element to the middle of the list between two real elements.

So in all real list entries, the value field will contain the actual value of the list entry. For them, I can initialize *ListEntry* by giving it a *Value* object in its constructor, so I don't need *Value* to be default constructible. In the sentinel, the value field will never be accessed. But unfortunately, since *Value* is not default constructible, the compiler doesn't let me create the sentinel object.

I could make the value member in *ListEntry* a pointer, boost::optional or something similar. I don't like this due to performance issues though.
Any ideas on how to store *Value* in *ListEntry* without performance/memory costs and without needing *Value* to be default constructible? It seems to me like there must be a way of getting a *Value* object without calling its constructors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a raw buffer and placement new :

```
template<class Value>
class ListEntry {
  alignas(Value) char storage[sizeof(Value)];
  ListEntry<Value> *prev;
  ListEntry<Value> *next;
};
```

Constructing the `Value` :

```
new (entry->storage) Value(/* params */);
```

Destructing the `Value` :

```
reinterpret_cast<Value*>(entry->storage)->~Value();
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, thanks. Looking at it, it seems to me like this concept (a generic buffer that might or might not hold an initialized object, offering new() and delete()) is general enough so there could be a implementation in std or boost. Is there any?

Comment: @Heinzi not that I know of. There exists `std::aligned_storage` for the buffer itself, but to be honest I can't get it straight so I stick to the plain char array. But there's nothing more to it really, so the closest thing would be `boost::optional` that also tracks whether the object is constructed or not.

Comment: `boost::optional` (which has a bool tracking "is it constructed", which you might think is overhead, but it is NOT, as what happens when your object is destroyed?  What if the destruction is a throw in an unexpected spot?) is a good choice, or `std::experimental::optional` from C++1z (port, with some changes). Another choice is `struct nothing {}; boost::variant<Value, nothing>`, which is basically a manual `optional` without easy cast-to-value and cast-to-bool. To roll your own, use a C++11 `union` (possibly with a bool saying if you need to destroy it) with `nothing` or an `aligned_storage`.

Answer (score 5):

You can split this into a base class and a node class, e.g.

```
class ListEntryBase {
    ListEntryBase *prev;
    ListEntryBase *next;
};

template<class Value>
class ListEntry : public ListEntryBase {
    Value value;
};

template<class Value>
class List {
    ListEntryBase sentinel;
};
```

This way you avoid creating an unneeded value and at the same time `Value` need not be default constructible.

Comment: Remember to check you're not on the sentinel before downcasting though.